# Login System don't work, I can't run form submit! CodeIgniter

Tags: php, codeigniter, authentication

I can't do authentication of my login, I don't know why, also my form doesn't "submit"!

> **Controller login.php**

```
<?php 


    class Login extends CI_Controller
    {



        public function index(){

            $this->load->view('admin/login');

        }

        public function auth(){

            //Model User

            $this->load->model('user_model');

            //Post

            $login = $this->input->post('username');
            $senha = $this->input->post('password');

            $query = $this->user_model->validate($login, $senha);


            if($query){

                    $data = array(
                        'username' => $this->input->post('username'),
                        'logged' => true
                    );

                    $this->session->userdata($data);

                    redirect('admin/index');
                }else{
                    redirect('admin/ease');
                    $this->session->set_flashdata('error_login', 'You dont have permission for access this area! Please, contact the support!');    
                }       

        }

    }

?>
```

> **Model user_model.php**

```
<?php   

    class User_model extends CI_Model
    {

        public function validate($login, $password){

                $this->db->where('username',$login);
                $this->db->where('password',$password);
                $this->db->where('status','1');
                $query = $this->db->get('usuario');

                if($query->num_rows == 1){
                    return true;
                }else{
                    return false;
                }
        }   

        //Verifica se o Usuario está logado
        public function logged(){

            $logged = $this->session->userdata('logged');

            if(!isset($logged) || $logged != true){
                echo 'Voce nao tem permissao para entrar nessa pagina. <a href="http://localhost/curriculo/login">Efetuar Login</a>';
                die();
            }

        }

    }

?>
```

> **View login.php**

```
<?php 
        echo form_open(site_url('login/auth'));

        echo "<br>";
        echo "<br>";
        echo form_label('Username', 'username');
        echo form_input('username', '');
        echo "<br>";
        echo form_label('Password', 'password');
        echo form_password('password', '');
        echo "<br>";
        echo form_submit('submit', 'Login');

        echo $this->session->flashdata('error_login');

        form_close();
?>
```

I was watching a form of a friend who used div instead of using pre-defined functions of the CI and it worked!

Comment: Maybe posting the form that is being rendered in the HTML could help us see what's going on there.

Comment: So, what's the problem?  What happens on your page?  What do you expect to happen?  Have you tried to debug it yourself?  Do you get any error messages?

Comment: This is the HTML!

<form action="htpp://localhost/curriculo/login/auth" method="post" accept-charset="utf-8"><br><br><label for="username">Username</label><input type="text" name="username" value=""  /><br><label for="password">Password</label><input type="password" name="password" value=""  /><br><input type="submit" name="submit" value="Login"  />

--- 

Man, when i send, i click on Login and nothing happens, The screen does not blink, you know?!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your `User_model/validate` method you have

```
if($query->num_rows == 1){ ... } // $query->num_rows is a method not property
```

It should be

```
if ($query->num_rows() > 0) { ... } // or if($query->num_rows())
```

Also you have

```
$this->db->where('username',$login);
$this->db->where('password',$password);
$this->db->where('status','1');
$query = $this->db->get('usuario');
```

You may use

```
$where = array('username' => $login, 'password' => $password, 'status' => 1);
$query = $this->db->get_where('usuario', $where);
```

Also, you can use

```
$where = array(...);
$this->db->select('username, password');
$this->db->from('usuario');
$this->db->where($where);
$query=$this->db->get();
```

[Read more about active record.](http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/database/active_record.html)

Also, in your `view` use

```
echo form_open('login/auth');
```

Instead of

```
echo form_open(site_url('login/auth'));
```

[Read more about form helper.](http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/helpers/form_helper.html)

BTW, you can use

```
return $query->num_rows();
```

Instead of

```
if($query->num_rows() == 1){
    return true;
}else{
    return false;
}
```

It's because, in your controller, `if($query)` will evaluate to `true` if there is grater than `0` otherwise it'll be `false` (if it's `0`).

Comment: well, i changed everything that you talked, but i still cant send the form, the screen not even "blink", you know?! 


<form action="htpp://localhost/curriculo/login/auth" method="post" accept-charset="utf-8"><br><br><label for="username">Username</label><input type="text" name="username" value=""  /><br><label for="password">Password</label><input type="password" name="password" value=""  /><br><input type="submit" name="submit" value="Login"  />        

There's something that u have change on the folder "Config"??

Comment: I found the error! Was it 

$config['base_url']= 'htpp://localhost/curriculo/';

htpp :\ changed and worked! Thanks man!